# Pythonic way of reading NUL in a file

Tags: python, ascii, binary-data, filereader, non-ascii-characters

I'm using python to read a text file with the segment below

(can't post a screenshot since i'm a noob) but this is what is looks like in notepad++:

```
NULSOHSOHNULNULNULSUBMesssage-ID:
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print(f.readline())
  File "C:\Python32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 7673: character maps to <undefined>
```

Opening the file as binary:

```
f = open('file.txt','rb')
f.readline()
```

gives me the text as binary

> b'\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1a\xb7Message-ID:

but how do I get the text as ascii ? And whats the easiest/pythonic way of handling this ?

Comment: It's not a text file, so you can't expect to read it as such.

Comment: The problem is not with `NUL` but with some other symbol. ASCII codec does not have any problem with ascii control characters.

Comment: The problem is with "byte 0x8f in position 7673", not with "byte 0x00 in position 1". I.e., your NUL is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with "byte 0x8f in position 7673", not with "byte 0x00 in position 1". I.e., your NUL is not the problem. If you look at the [cp-1252 codepage on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), you can see that 0x8f has no corresponding character.

The larger issue is that your file is not in a single encoding: it appears to be a mix of binary framing of text segments. What you really need to do is figure out the format of this file and parse it into binary pieces (or perhaps some richer data structure, like a tuple, list, dict, object, etc), then decode the text pieces into unicode if you need to process further.

Comment: You're right the file appears to have ascii segments framed in binary characters. I like the approach you've suggested. Thanks !

Comment: "The Windows-1252 code points 0x81, 0x8D, 0x8F, 0x90, 0x9D are unassigned. They do not yet represent any characters" - http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-double-conversion.html

Answer (score 2):

When opening a file in text mode, you can specifically tell which encoding to use:

```
f = open('file.txt','r',encoding='ascii')
```

However your real problem is different: the binary piece that you cited can not be read as ASCII, because the byte `\xb7` is outside of ASCII range (0-127). The exception traceback tells that Python is using cp1252 codec by default, which cannot decode your file either.

You need either to figure out which encoding the file has, or to handle it as binary all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps open it in read the correct read mode?

```
f = open('file.txt','r')
f.readline()
```